# Adding "0" value to blank values while importing data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets, which are fed by data imported from multiple external excel files. To complete this action, I successfully built VBA code that allows the user to open the files.

Behind the scenes, one of the subs imports data from the General Ledger raw data into a spreadsheet with multiple columns. I am attaching a couple screen grabs here to show what is happening:

The pre-existing data looks like this:
[image: Pre-Populated Data]

Raw data once downloads will look like this:
[image: RawData]

Once the macro runs, the previous columns populate as intended, but because the last two columns are populated intermittently, they end up doing this:
[image]

I only summarized columns in these images, as the workbook has 28 columns preceding the two columns.

Due to the size of the data and the macro itself, I would like to maintain the structure of the code. Especially since it is intended that this macro be transferred to other general ledger workbooks.

My macro looks like this (summarized for time):

```
1. Sub Import_GL1001
2. Dim FileToOpen As Variant
3. Dim OpenBook As Workbook
4. Application.ScreenUpdating = False
5. FileToOpen=Application.GetOpenFileName(Title="Import_GL1001",FileFilter:="ExcelFiles (*xlsx*),*xlsx*")
6. If FileToOpen<> False Then
7. Set OpenBook=Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
8. OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$A$2:$A$1500").Copy
9. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GL 1001.10").Range("A"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
10. OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$B$2:$B$1500").Copy
11. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GL 1001.10").Range("B"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecialxlPasteValues
12. ......
13. OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$AC$2:AC$1500").Copy
14. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GL 1001.10").Range("AD"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPastevalues
15. OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$AD$2:$AD$1500").Copy
15. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GL 1001.10").Range("AF"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecialxlPasteValues
```

In an ideal world, the values would copy and paste as is, blanks and all, so when the macro is run in the future the two columns in question do not change position based on the last blank cell. I tried multiple methods and variations, but the only logical thing I could think of is if I manage to find a way to insert a "0" into each cell that is blank every time the data is imported, without changing all the blank cells (i.e. if we only have 30 rows of data, I don't want all of the blank cells in AF:AF to be "0"). If the cells have a value at all, then that means that the macro itself won't have to be dramatically retooled.

Comment: Your links are wrongly placed in the que question and cannot be seen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. The last row where to paste the values should be calculated only once, based on a column you know that it is all the time filled with values.

```
Dim lastERow As Long, sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GL 1001.10")
lastERow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).row 'last empty row
```

2. Then use this reference for all the columns where you intend pasting starting from the same empty cell row:

```
'your existing code
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$A$2:$A$1500").Copy
sh.Range("A" & lastERow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'...
'...
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$AC$2:AC$1500").Copy
sh.Range("AD" & lastERow).PasteSpecial xlPastevalues
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$AD$2:$AD$1500").Copy
sh.Range("AF" & lastERow).PasteSpecial xlPastevalues
```

In this way, the code will paste starting from the same empty row, in all columns.

If you want following your way of solving, please run the next code, but **after your existing code runs**. It will take the reference from the last filled cell of the A:A column:

```
Sub ZeroInEmptyCells()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rngEmpt As Range
  
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GL 1001.10")
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in column A:A
  
  On Error Resume Next 'if no empty cells, the next code line will return an error (without this line...):
   Set rngEmpt = Union(sh.Range("AD1:AD" & lastRow), sh.Range("AF1:AF" & lastRow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
 On Error GoTo 0
 If Not rngEmpt Is Nothing Then rngEmpt.value = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked PERFECTLY! I was scouring the interwebs for over a week, and I tried the Microsoft Community but apparently nobody there knew how to help me lol.